# Gekko - repeat cycle and oxygen step for wastewater modeling

Tags: python, modeling, gekko

I am moving some wastewater metabolic models across to Python, specifically some on polyphosphate accumulating organisms (PAOs). I have managed to move the model into Python and solving using Gekko which is great! (Still a few tweaks in the equations to be implemented).

[Anaerobic storage polymer consumption](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n3FxZ.png)

I can get the change in O2 to wokr and simluate supply of oxygen, however, I don’t quite know how to get it to repeat through multiple cycles to observe the changes in storage polymers over numerous cycles.

This code for a step in Oxygen (O2) worked for the initial cycle:

`t = np.linspace(0, 19, 19) m.time = t`

`O2_step = np.zeros(19)`

`O2_step[17:] = 0.05`

`O2 = m.Param(value=O2_step)`

I have tried the `m.Options.CYCLECOUNT = 3` but it doesn’t seem to do the trick. Is there another way to set this up?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you post a minimal working example that reproduces the issue posed in your question? The response can be more specific with a complete example.

Comment: Thanks John, do you want me to share my model?

Comment: Yes, please share it in a StackOverflow question with just enough detail to show the issue and help resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Every time `m.solve()` is called, the solution is time-shifted to the left by `m.options.TIME_SHIFT` (default=1). The new initial conditions are taken from the next time step and the problem is solved again. Change `m.options.TIME_SHIFT=3` to make the 3rd time point the initial condition for the next solve. Set `m.options.TIME_SHIFT=0` to have no change in the initial conditions. This allows different `O2` profiles to be tested such as:

```py
O2.value = np.ones(19)*0.5; O2.value[15:]=0.7
m.solve()

O2.value = np.ones(19)*0.6; O2.value[15:]=0.7
m.solve()

O2.value = np.ones(19)*0.8; O2.value[15:]=0.7
m.solve()
```